# Adding error variance to output of predict()

Tags: r, random, linear-regression, prediction

I am attempting to take a linear model fitted to empirical data, eg:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .01)
y <- x + .25*rnorm(101)
model <- (lm(y ~ x))
summary(model)
# R^2 is .6208
```

Now, what I would like to do is use the `predict` function (or something similar) to create, from x, a vector y of predicted values that shares the error of the original relationship between x and y. Using predict alone gives perfectly fitted values, so R^2 is 1 e.g:

```
y2 <- predict(model)
summary(lm(y2 ~ x))
# R^2 is 1
```

I know that I can use `predict(model, se.fit = TRUE)` to get the standard errors of the prediction, but I haven't found an option to incorporate those into the prediction itself, nor do I know exactly how to incorporate these standard errors into the predicted values to give the correct amount of error.

Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `simulate(model)` ?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .01)
y <- x + .25*rnorm(101)
model <- (lm(y ~ x))
y2 <- predict(model)
y3 <- simulate(model)
matplot(x,cbind(y,y2,y3),pch=1,col=1:3)
```

If you need to do it it by hand you could use

```
y4 <- rnorm(nobs(model),mean=predict(model),
            sd=summary(model)$sigma)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, perfect! I don't know if I was just honing in too strongly on `predict()`, but I didn't find the simulate function anywhere in my searching.

Comment: I think it's not as widely known as it should be

Comment: Actually, I need to be able to feed the function a new vector of x values to predict from based on the model, rather than simulate from the original vector - however your 'by hand' method works exactly as I wanted

Comment: I would like `simulate` to take a `newdata` argument as well, but it doesn't generally

Comment: @BenBolker I have a similar issue to that raised here - I'm wondering if after 6 years there is now a function that takes `newdata` as an argument to predict with error variance off a given model?